# SQL-Server return exactly 4 results per group

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) IDCount
, SUM(ValueA) SumA
, SUM(ValueB) SumB
, FlagA
, FlagB
, GroupColumn
FROM
(   SELECT w.ID
    , x.ValueA
    , x.ValueB
    , y.FlagA
    , y.FlagB
    , w.GroupColumn

    FROM tableW w
    LEFT JOIN tableX x ON w.ID = x.ID
    LEFT JOIN tableY y ON w.ID = y.ID

    WHERE w.SomeColumn = SomeValue
) res

GROUP BY res.GroupColumn, res.FlagA, res.FlagB

ORDER BY res.GroupColumn, res.FlagA DESC, res.FlagB DESC
```

FlagA and FlagB are flags, so they only are ever 1 or 0.  I need this to return 4 rows for every GroupColumn grouping, one for each combination of flags.

What's happening now is, sometimes there is nothing coming back from that inner select, so it just doesn't return anything. In that case I only get back 3 rows for that group.  What I need is for that 4th row to return anyways with 0 values for IDCount, SumA and SumB.

Hopefully this is clear.  Thanks in advance for any help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your subquery your outer table, and your flags/Group your inner table, and join the two.

So first to get all 4 combinations for each Group Column:

```
SELECT  w.GroupColum, f.A, f.B
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT GroupColumn FROM TableW) AS W
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)) AS f (A, B)
```

This gives you all the combinations you need, regardless of whether or not the combination exists in your data. Then you can join your data back to it:

```
SELECT  IDCount = COUNT(res.ID),
        SumA = SUM(res.ValueA),
        SumB = SUM(res.ValueB),
        FlagA = f.A,
        FlagB = f.B,
        w.GroupColumn
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT GroupColumn FROM TableW) AS w
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)) AS f (A, B)
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT w.ID, x.ValueA, x.ValueB, y.FlagA, y.FlagB, w.GroupColumn
            FROM tableW w
            LEFT JOIN tableX x ON w.ID = x.ID
            LEFT JOIN tableY y ON w.ID = y.ID
            WHERE w.SomeColumn = SomeValue
        ) res
            ON res.GroupColumn = w.GroupColumn
            AND res.FlagA = f.A
            AND res.FlagB = f.B
GROUP BY f.A, f.B, w.GroupColumn;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Unfortunately, I'm getting the same results as  before.  I changed the ON to:
) res
 ON res.GroupColumn = W.GroupColumn
 AND f.A = res.FlagA
 AND f.B = res.FlagB

The only way I could get 4 results was to remove these two lines completely:
            AND f.A = res.FlagA
            AND f.B = res.FlagB
But, that just gives me the same result four times.

Comment: I had some of the columns/joins messed up. Does it work for you now?

Comment: Changing res.GroupColumn in the outer select statement to w.GroupColumn solved this for me.  Thank you so much for this clever solution!